# Higher dimensional analogues of the argument principle?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, dimensional-analysis

I know there are higher dimensional analogues of the argument principle.

(See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_argument)

But I do not have books about it and I cannot find anything of value on the internet for free.

Plz give me references or explainations.

I would like an example of how one can find the zero's of functions in 3 Dimensions with an integral.

I believe it works as follows :

1) The function needs to be "3D-analytic" , and by that I mean the derivative can be given by the limit

$$ \lim_{h->0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$

Where any infinitesimal $h$ will give the same limit as any other infinitesimal $h_2$.
(By "any" I mean in any direction of the dimension.)

This is the natural analogue of complex differentiable.

2) The integral is taken over a closed surface that contains a volume.
The surface must be topologically isomorphic to a sphere. ( no holes , no selfintersections , continu )

3) Just like the argument principle , the direction of the integral matters.
Hence we riemann sum the points with respect to the direction we are going in.
( compare : for contour integration if our (piecewise) path goes from - to + we add if it goes from + to - we substract )

4) The "3D argument principle" then computes $CZ$.
$C$ is some constant and $Z$ is the number of zero's - the number of poles within the volume.

Is this correct ?

---

The analytic proof of the PNT constructs a counting function for the primes based on the zero's of the Riemann zeta function.

An important part of that proof is the argument principle.

I wonder if there are some similar applications of the "3D argument principle " as described above that have been used in number theory.

I wonder what functions in 3D are associated with (number-theoretical) counting functions*.

(* such as used in the proof of PNT with the argument principle (used on the complex plane).)

Comment: I wouldn't downvote this question, but my best guess is that the downvotes are due to the lack of precision in your question: why are both higher-dimensional argument principles and the proof of the prime number theorem appearing in the same question? Without more clarification, I'd suggest you separate these into two questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, the Argument Principle is in the context of meromorphic functions. However, the higher-dimensional analogue in the context of smooth functions comes from the theory of the degree of maps and winding numbers.

In particular, suppose $W$ is a compact $n$-dimensional oriented manifold with boundary, $f\colon W \to \Bbb R^n$ is smooth, and $f\big|_{\partial W} \ne 0$. If $0$ is a regular value of $f$, then $f^{-1}(0)$ consists of a finite number of points $x_1,\dots,x_k\in W$, each of which appears with a sign $\epsilon_j$ ($+1$ if $df_{x_j}\colon T_{x_j}W\to\Bbb R^n$ is orientation-preserving, and $-1$ if it is orientation-reversing). Then 
$$\sum_{j=1}^k \epsilon_j = \text{deg}\left(\frac{f}{\|f\|}\Bigg|_{\partial W}\colon \partial W\to S^{n-1}\right)\,.$$

Comment: In the case $n=2$, $W\subset\Bbb R^2$, and $f$ holomorphic, the $\epsilon_j$ are all always $+1$, and so we merely count the roots in $W$. The degree on the right-hand side is the winding number of $f(\partial W)$, which is exactly what $\dfrac1{2\pi i}\displaystyle\int_{\partial W} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$ computes.

The best reference I know on such matters is Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology*. See pp. 110-111 and 144, in particular.

**EDIT**: To respond to your additional comments/questions, the one-variable calculus definition of derivative extends to $\Bbb C$ *only* because $\Bbb C$ is a field. Once you move on to $\Bbb R^n$, the derivative becomes a linear transformation with a limit property but cannot itself be given by the sort of limit you desire. Only *directional* derivatives have the single-variable calculus definition. (In time, you will learn some rigorously done multivariable calculus.) The degree calculation I have given above *can* indeed be represented by an integral (but, once again, you'll have a bit to learn to understand this): Choose an $(n-1)$-form $\omega$ on $S^{n-1}$ with $\displaystyle\int_{S^{n-1}}\omega=1$, and compute $\displaystyle\int_{\partial W} \left(\tfrac{f}{\|f\|}\right)^*\omega$. Alternatively, compute
$$\tfrac1{\text{vol}(S^{n-1})}\int_{\partial W} f^*\left(\tfrac{x_1\, dx_2\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n - x_2\, dx_1\wedge dx_3\wedge \dots \wedge dx_n + (-1)^{n-1} x_n\, dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_{n-1}}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{n/2}}\right)\,.$$ 
 This is in fact an immediate generalization of the integral appearing in the argument principle.

There are generalizations of the Residue Theorem (which is where the Argument Principle comes from) to *meromorphic* functions in $\Bbb C^n$. This is also a rather rich subject; some comments were made in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612905/multidimensional-complex-integral-of-a-holomorphic-function-with-no-poles/613018#613018).

Comment: This is not completely clear to me. Im not familiar with all this notation. And Im not an expert in Differential Topology.
I edited my OP , maybe that can affect the answer in a positive way. I think the answer is probably correct but It needs to be longer for ... beginners :)
Also I wondered about the possible connections to number theory. In particular I completely do not know what you mean by "deg". Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you don't know what an oriented manifold with boundary is, think of a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ together with the region it bounds. If you don't know what a regular value is, ignore that-replace that with "if $f$ is nice at points mapping to $0$." You can probably also profitably ignore the stuff about orientations. Degree is the generalization of winding number to higher-dimensional spheres, which can be defined geometrically but is easier to define using homology theory. To really understand the answer, you should learn differential topology!

Answer (score -2):

Back in the year 1991 I found the higher dimensional complex numbers, they bear many similarities with the ordinary complex plane yet there are all kinds of differences and subtilities that come along with them.

The complex plane is more or less defined via stating $i^2 = -1$, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you can do the same via stating $j^3 = -1$.
The number one correspondents with a unit vector on the x-axis,
the number $j$ lies on the y-axis while
the number $j^2$ is on the z-axis.

A very important property is the fact that $i$ from the complex plane does not exist in 3-dimensional space.

During the last two years I have made many updates on that, you can find it in the next link:

http://kinkytshirts.nl/rootdirectory/just_some_math/3d_complex_stuff.htm

It takes some time to understand the stuff involved, the best thing is to multiply a few times those 3D numbers and try to understand the Cauchy-Riemann equations for 3 dimensions...

Good luck with it.

Comment: This seems a bit 'cranky' and doesn't appear to answer the question.

Comment: This is a nice answer.

Comment: $j$ by definition is a root of $x^3+1=0$ -- however the coefficients of this equation are all complex numbers, and since $\mathbb{C}$ is an algebraically closed field, $j$ is a complex number -- in other words, the set $\{1,j,j^2\}$ is linearly dependent over $\mathbb{R}$, and thus cannot be used to define a 3-dimensional vector space over the reals, as you are suggesting. By the Frobenius theorem, the only division algebras over the reals (division algebras have the properties of $\mathbb{C}$, but are in even more general) have dimension 1 ($\mathbb{R}$), 2 ($\mathbb{C}$), or 4 ($\mathbb{H}$)

Comment: a 3-dimensional division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ is impossible. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity In fact, a genius no less than William Rowan Hamilton already experienced firsthand that trying to do what you are suggesting is impossible -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_quaternions#Hamilton.27s_discovery -- so not only is this answer not relevant to the question being asked, it is also very wrong and hence very misleading, because it promises things which are not even possible.

Comment: @Chill2Macht -- This is simply a 3-dimensional Real algebra, [defined by the multiplication table][1] $$\begin{matrix} 1&j&k \\ j&k&{^-}1 \\ k&{^-}1&{^-}j \end{matrix}$$ The answerer doesn't claim it's a division algebra. Indeed, in his link, he discusses the divisors of zero (as well as exponentials, magnetic monopoles, and "precious professional professors"!). It's quite interesting, though of course it doesn't answer the question. [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field#Structure_coefficients

Comment: @mr_e_man You're right, I am being unfairly judgmental. My impression was that since the argument principle is relevant for meromorphic functions (i.e. _quotients_ of analytic functions), some notion of division for the corresponding algebra should be necessary for the algebra to allow a "generalization to 3D" of the argument principle. But honestly I'm pretty bad at complex analysis (even compared to other fields of math, which I'm also bad at), so my opinion here probably shouldn't be considered too relevant. Sorry about having been rude/snotty.

Comment: @Chill2Macht -- There is division in this algebra, only it's undefined on a certain plane and a line. I don't know the significance of that for this question. I don't really know Complex analysis either.