# Does the argument principle generalize to projective space?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

**Questions:**

**1.** Does the argument principle, which is valid for $\mathbb{C}$, generalize to higher-dimensional spaces $\mathbb{C}^n$, and to complex projective spaces $\mathbb{CP}^n$? Or at the very least to $\mathbb{CP}^2$?

**2.** Is it true that $\oint_C \frac{(f+g)'(z)}{(f+g)(z)}dz \ge \min \{ \oint_c \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz, \oint_c \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}dz \} $? And if so, why?

> $$\oint_C\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz = 2\pi i(N-P) $$ where $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function inside a closed contour $C$ with no zeros and poles on $C$, and $N$ is the number of zeros inside $C$ counted up to multiplicity, and $P$ is the number of poles inside $C$ counted up to multiplicity.

**Context:** I am trying to prove that for any rational functions $f,g$, that $$(N-P)_{f+g} \ge \min \{  (N-P)_f , (N-P)_g  \} $$ This is necessary to show that the Riemann-Roch space of a divisor $D$ is actually a vector space. See under definition 21.2. [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-782-introduction-to-arithmetic-geometry-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT18_782F13_lec21.pdf). Note that obviously rational functions are meromorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for an answer to your first question today and found this:

[Higher dimensional analogues of the argument principle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634243/higher-dimensional-analogues-of-the-argument-principle)

Comment: Yes, I believe this does answer my question -- in order to extend the generalizations discussed from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{CP}^n$ one just has to use affine charts, which generally isn't difficult at all. Thank you for finding this for me -- I really appreciate it!