# Cauchy integral of complex analysis in several variables

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Let $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$
If a function $f(z_1,z_2)$ is holomorphic in some domain $\mathcal{D}$, how to evaluate the Cauchy integral

> $$\iint_{\mathcal{D}}\frac{f(z_1,z_2)}{(v_1-z_1)(v_2-z_2)}dz_1dz_2$$

For normal Cauchy integral we can use residue theorem, so are there any similar theorems for multivariate case?

Comment: This is an integral over a region, not over a curve, so neither the Cauchy integral formula nor the residue theorem should apply.

Comment: As written, the integral doesn't make sense. You're integrating a two-form over a four (real) dimensional object. You may be interested in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612905

Comment: Do you understand the definition of holomorphic function in several variables?

Comment: @AdityaKumar holomorphic in each variable?

Comment: No. The definition of holomorphic function in several complex variables is not so simple. Tbh, your question doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @AdityaKumar I see different versions of the definition of holomorphic function in several variables. One is holomorphic in each variable and the Cauchy integral is defined as the iterated integral on a polydisc. Another version defines high-dimensional "complex differentiable" first and the function is called holomorphic on $\mathcal{U}$ if it is complex differentiable at each point in $\mathcal{U}$.

Comment: @mrf I've been a little confused about the definition of multi-dimension Cauchy integral. Is it the iterated integral over a polydisc?

Comment: @AdityaKumar The definition of holomorphic in several variables that Claire gave in equivalent to whatever definition you know.

Comment: The problem is it looks like a volume integral over $D.$ Is that what you mean?

Comment: @zhw. Yes. But I am quite unfamiliar with volume integral. In the textbook of <<The principles of algebraic geometry>>, the high dimensional residue theorem is valid for complex function in several variables and the cauchy integral is the volume form. I was just wondering can I just treat the integral in my question as two iterated ordinary cauchy integral? So first fix $z_2$ and integrate $z_1$ and apply residue theorem if any singular points.

Comment: I don't think the Cauchy integral is an integral over the interior. It's an integral over the boundary, just as it is in one complex variable.

Comment: @Yikai我不知道他对不对，我后来自己搞出来了，可能我这个问题提的也不好说的不清楚。谢谢！

Comment: @Yikai不好意思啊没印象，我的名字6楼墙上有

Comment: @Yikai哦好像知道！你是RongYu师弟吧！艾玛早说！之前他帮你向我问TX的wechat，原来是你啊！名字你问rong吧，我不太想把个人信息写到网上

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I know what you mean, but with the conditions of the Cauchy integral,

holomorphic in both arguments for $z_1\in U$ and $z_2\in V$ and with $\overline{\Delta_1}\subset{U}$ and $\overline{\Delta_2}\subset{V}$ using

$D:= \delta\Delta_1 \times  \delta\Delta_2 \subset U\times V$, $\enspace$ I don't see a problem to write :

$\displaystyle \iint_{\delta\Delta_1 \times  \delta\Delta_2}\frac{f(z_1,z_2)}{(v_1-z_1)(v_2-z_2)}dz_1dz_2=i2\pi\int_{\delta\Delta_2 }\frac{f(v_1,z_2)}{v_2-z_2}dz_2=-(2\pi)^2 f(v_1,v_2)$